# Keyboard shortcuts keep resetting

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, emacs

There is a conflict between the Ubuntu keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-Alt-S` (which does "toggle shaded state") and the emacs macro `Ctrl-Alt-S`, which invokes `forward-search-regex`, which of course is vastly more useful than "toggle shaded state."

In Keyboard Settings, I deleted the shortcut for "toggle shaded state," and that makes the emacs macro work properly. But sometimes the Ubuntu shortcut reasserts itself unexpectedly, so I have to go to System Settings to delete that shortcut again. It doesn't always happen on restart. Today it happened while I was working in emacs - one minute `Ctrl-Alt-S` invoked the regular expression search, the next minute it went crazy.

How can I delete the Ubuntu keyboard shortcut permanently?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @ElderGeek, I'm using 14.04.

Comment: I should add that this happens on multiple machines.

Answer (score 2):

In 14.04 System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows

Highlight Toggle Shaded State.

Backspace should disable it.

It's my understanding that many of these are hard-coded and the fact that disabling doesn't stick is a bug. More information about it and the option to subscribe to notifications regarding it are available [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1063617)

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Every time I do that, the macro resets itself after some period of time, so if I look at that macro in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Windows, it is no longer disabled. I am trying to figure out how to disable it permanently, since it doesn't seem to work if I do it in System Settings.

Comment: I can confirm this bug and am researching further

Comment: More information about the and the option to subscribe to notifications regarding it are available here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1063617